# Escaping single quotes for ssh command

Tags: bash, ssh

I want to write wrapper function that will control timeout of executing of other functions.

Something like this:

```
function timeout_exec {
  timeout 2s $*
}
```

I have a problem when I want to execute ssh command via my wrapper

```
timeout_exec ssh server1 echo '$HOME'
```

I expect that HOME variable will be from remote server not local. Is there any way to escape single quotas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
timeout_exec() { timeout 2s "$@"; }
```